# Improving django search

Tags: python, mysql, django, search

I have the following search:

```
titles = Title.objects.filter(title__icontains=search)
```

If this is a search to find:

```
Thomas: Splish, Splash, Splosh
```

I can type in something like "Thomas" or "Thomas: Splish, Splash, Splosh" and it will work.

However, if I type in something like `"Thomas Splash"`, it will not work. How would I improve the search to do something like that (also note that if we split on words, the comma and other non-alphanumerics should be ignored -- for example, the split words should not be "Thomas:", "Splish," but rather "Thomas", "Splish", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of search is starting to push the boundaries of django and the ORM.  Once it gets to this level of complexity I always switch over to a system that is built entirely for search.  I dig [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org), so I usually go for [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Keep in mind that full text searching is a subsystem all unto itself, but can really add a lot of value to your site.

Answer (score 1):

As Django models are using database queries there is not much magic you can do.

You could split your search by non-alphanumeric chars and search objects containing all words but this will not be smart and efficient.

If you want something really smart maybe you should check out haystack:

http://haystacksearch.org/